# Test convergence of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Test convergence of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm dx$

I was solving it my own way. But, I think I messed with trigonometry here.

Let, $x=\sec^2\theta$ so, $\mathrm dx=2\sec^2\theta\tan\theta\mathrm d\theta$
$$2\int_1^0 \frac{\cos (\sec^2\theta)}{\sec \theta}\sec^2\theta\tan\theta\mathrm d\theta$$
$$2\int_1^0 \color{red}{\sec\theta}\sec\theta\tan\theta\mathrm d\theta$$

I guess, I had removed $\cos$ wrong way. So, I am not writing the whole solution now. If it is correct than, I will show my whole work. Cause, as far as I know it is wrong.

---

Take again, $u=\tan \theta$ So, $\mathrm du = 2 \sec^2\theta \tan\theta \mathrm d\theta$

$$2\int_\dfrac{\pi}{4}^\dfrac{\pi}{2} u\mathrm du$$

I am not writing anymore since, [he said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215490/test-convergence-of-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x-sqrtx-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1#comment8750018_4215490) earlier thing was wrong.

Comment: More work will never hurt your cause here.  Isn't there some function that has $\sec^2x$ as its derivative?

Comment: @abiessu But, I was thinking that $$\cos (\sec x)\neq 1$$ Cause, $$\cos (\frac{1}{\cos x})$$ there's another $\cos$ inside $\cos$ function. So, I was thinking that's wrong.

Comment: You are correct: $\cos(\sec x)$ is not the same as $1$, and $\cos(\sec^2 x)$ is not the same as $\sec x$. It helps to use the right words: these *compositions* of functions are not the same as *products* of functions.